# Can we change the Low Quality Posts comment?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reviewing

I was recently going through some posts in the [Low Quality Posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts), and one answer (which I won't link here) I recommended that it be deleted, and got review to leave a comment telling the user that it wasn't a proper answer, and thought that was it.

Later (just now), I happened to find the same post while reading some answers to the question, and noticed the comment left below it that said

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - From Review

This caught my attention, as it tells new users who don't have a correct answer, that they should ask a question here about how to correct their answer, which, 99% of the time isn't what we want.

I think we should change this message to direct the answerer to Stack Overflow in order to avoid confusing them. Imagine a new user's confusion and irritation when, after having been told to ask a question about their code, we then tell them that their question is off-topic and they get downvoted into oblivion.

Therefore, we should change the message commented when people click "This is a "I'm having the problem as well" answer", as it misleads new users. I propse we change it to something along the lines of

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but please make sure to read their [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before hand, and to make your question of suitable quality  - From Review

Comment: I don't think the new one is any better.  That particular answer should have been redirected to SO but I don't think that they should always be redirected in general.

Comment: Personally, if I think the comment is not suitable for the mentioned answer, I'll open up that question, recommend deletion, refresh the question page, and edit or delete the comment.